# Multi-permissions login system for a web DBMS System (PHP/MYSQL/JAVASCRIPT/AJAX)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, logging, permissions

Any suggestions for a multi-user/multi-permission-levels management module for web applications?

I am actually  developing a wide Data Base Management System which handles many tasks, so I need multiple user accounts, each account can only operate on special functionalities of the web application.
I'm developing using (PHP/MYSQL/JAVASCRIPT/AJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: [Cartalyst Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1)

From the website:

> A modern and framework agnostic authorization and authentication
>   package featuring groups, permissions, custom hashing algorithms and
>   additional security features.